# Does a PhD give you global mobility in the job market?

Tags: career-path

I am thinking of doing a PhD in Condensed Matter Physics at the Indian Institute of Science, which is not a bad place to graduate from as far as I've heard.

The downside is I'll be a little on the older side by the time I graduate, and in India, there seems to be a starting faculty preference of 35 years. I would like to know if I'd be able to practice physics somewhere else in the world after getting a PhD in the area.

I've heard the US is pretty open in terms of hiring foreign candidates, but Europe is not. What about other English speaking countries like Australia, New Zealand, Canada, etc? Does a Phd open up career opportunities world-wide?

Comment: Not PhD but good research (which comes through PhD usually)

Comment: I think Europe is very open to foreign candidates, at least judging from the amount of foreign colleagues I had during my PhD and postdoc in the Netherlands.

Comment: *I've heard the US is pretty open in terms of hiring foreign candidates, but Europe is not* — I strongly disagree.  Research groups I am aware of all have at least 50% foreigners, and the one I'm working in is more than 90% foreign.  In some fields, 100% foreign is not uncommon (I have experience in Netherlands, Sweden).

Comment: @gerrit I notice that the OP is from India. How many in your group are from Asia?

Comment: @scaaahu In our group, three are from south Asia (none from the rest of Asia, but we previously had an Iranian member as well).

Comment: @gerrit Thanks. Although the sample size is tiny, at least we have counter proof to what the OP claims.

Comment: It may depend on the country and the field.  For example, it may be difficult or impossible for a PhD student from Iran to research nuclear physics in France, Netherlands, or elsewhere — although that might be the same in the USA.

Comment: @gerrit: In your comment, does "foreign" mean "from a different country" or "from outside Europe"?

Comment: @NateEldredge It means "from a different country" (than the institute location).  The percentage from outside Europe is smaller.

Comment: How many Phds in physics from IISc have landed up with an academic job outside India? I don't think many.

Comment: I suspect that it is very difficult to get a job in other countries (doesn't matter in European, American, Canadian, or even Asian countries) when you are foreigner. I do not have a clear proof for my claim but based on my experience I think you should be way better than other candidates to get a job in another country. Especially if you are from a third world country. About Canadian universities, I have seen many job ads saying that they priorities hiring Canadian citizens and permanent residents.

Answer (score 3):

There are two aspects to this question: the hiring process within an employer's institution, and the immigration policies which allow a foreign worker to move to another country and begin employment.

I think with respect to the first question—the hiring process and preferences of an individual employer—I think that in general, employers are looking for the best-qualified candidates, regardless of their origin. There are certain obvious exceptions to this (for instance, a foreign national will have a hard time getting a position at a National Nuclear Security Administration facility in the US), but otherwise, people will want the person best-suited for the job. I think this is true both in the US and Europe.

The other step is the national immigration policies. This is where things become more complex. For instance, if you are a non-European Union citizen, then your employer will need to certify that your experiences uniquely qualify you for this position, which can delay the hiring process somewhat. Similarly, employers in the US have to wait for you to obtain an appropriate visa, which can delay your start date significantly. This makes it sometimes less advantageous to hire foreign employees. (But this is a "speed bump," rather than an insurmountable obstacle.)